# How can I check and find the last character of the e-mail address from letters and numbers using Python?

Tags: python, email, numbers, character, letter

I forgot the last 3 characters of the Gmail e-mail address of my Tiktok account. How to write and check individual letters and numbers consisting of A-Z, a-z and 0-9 letters and numbers in Python? i.e. how can I find it using A-Z, a-z and 0-9 letters and numbers in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
import string

EMAIL_LOCAL_NAME_PREFIX = 'your_email_local_name_prefix'
EMAIL_DOMAIN_NAME = 'gmail.com'
CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits # (A-Z, a-z, 0-9)

for p in itertools.product(CHARS, repeat=3):
    email_local_name_suffix = ''.join(p)
    email = f'{EMAIL_LOCAL_NAME_PREFIX}{email_local_name_suffix}@{EMAIL_DOMAIN_NAME}'
    print(email)
```

**Output:**

```
your_email_local_name_prefixaaa@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefixaab@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefixaac@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefixaad@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefixaae@gmail.com
...
your_email_local_name_prefix995@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefix996@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefix997@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefix998@gmail.com
your_email_local_name_prefix999@gmail.com
```

*Note there are `238328` email addresses to check if you include uppercase letters... [@Shai V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21477238/shai-v) pointed out a good point that you might not need to check for both uppercase and lowercase letters. If that is the case you can use `CHARS = string.ascii_lowercase_letters + string.digits # (a-z, 0-9)`. Subsequently, you will only need to check `46656` email addresses.*